# Is there a way to execute an SQL statement with multiple variables and an operator in DBeaver?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

I'm currently running SQL statements with variables like this

```sql
@set var1 = 'hello';
@set var2 = 'world';

select * 
from "Table" 
where col1 = ${var1};
```

So far this has been working perfectly fine but I recently tried to run a statement that contained the `AND` operator.

```sql
select * 
from "Table" 
where col1 = ${var1} and col2 = ${var2};
```

DBeaver throws the following error:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "and"

The SQL statement works when I run it like so

```sql
select * 
from "Table" 
where col1 = 'hello' and col2 = 'world';
```

Any ideas on how I can use two variables in one statement?

Comment: Your variables include the single quotes and the semicolons you entered after the equal sign. So your `where` evaluates to `where col1 = 'hello'; and col2 = 'world';`. Just remove the semicolons in the first two lines, you don't need them.

Comment: Oh wow, that worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: I made my comment into a proper answer, so that it's easier to find should anyone else look for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables include the single quotes and the semicolons you entered after the equal sign. So your `where` evaluates to

```
where col1 = 'hello'; and col2 = 'world';;
```

Causing a syntax error after the first semicolon. Just remove the semicolons in the first two lines, you don't need them:

```
@set var1 = 'hello'
@set var2 = 'world'
select * 
from "Table" 
where col1 = ${var1} and col2 = ${var2};--where col1 = 'hello' and col2 = 'world';
```